# Cocos2d 2.0.3 Use of undeclared identifier 'glColor4f'

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0, kobold2d

I am trying to compile my project after switching to cocos2d 2.0.3 and I keep getting this error. (Use of undeclared identifier 'glColor4f') Is there something else that I should use instead of this method.

```
glColor4f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
```

Comment: post line of code. maybe you use wrong parameters.

Comment: I just edited my original post and included the code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ccDrawColor4F as a replacement.

```
ccDrawColor4F(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, cocos2d 2.0 uses OpenGL ES 2.0, that does not have such function. You can  use glColorPointer instead.

Comment: `glColorPointer` doesn't exist in OpenGLES2.0 either. You probably mean `glVertexAttribPointer`.

Answer (score 0):

```
DrawPrimitives::setDrawColor4F(r, g, b, a);
```